# ConTexT, disable node text indenting

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation, context

I have a problem with TikZ picture under ConTexT. If I set it up for document wide indenting such as "setindenting[medium,yes]", then the problem is that tikz will always indent the text in a node as well. Is there a way for me to setup the document indenting but however tell TikZ not to indent the text inside a node?

```
\setuppapersize[letter][letter]
\setuplayout[height=9.6in,backspace=80pt,location=middle]
\usemodule[tikz]   
\setupindenting[medium, yes]
\starttext

\tikzstyle{sensor}=
[draw,
text centered, 
text width=6em, fill=red!20,
minimum height=12em, rounded corners]

\starttikzpicture
    \path node (naveq) [sensor] {Navigation equations};
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Does adding \noindent to the text in the node not work?

Answer (score 1):

A correct approach is to avoid all the artifacts like those in the above example is to add `\forgetall` as part of the definition of `\starttikzpicture`. `\forgetall` disables *all* attributes: indentation, alignment, parskip, linenumbering, etc.

As a quick hack, you can use

```
\starttikzpicture
    \forgetall
    \path node (naveq) [sensor] {Navigation equations };
\stoptikzpicture
```

Comment: My dear Aditya, isn't it kinda radical the above approach to `\forgetall` ?

Comment: @doed: In what situation would you like to keep some of these?